# Switch Build Variant on All Modules in a Multimodule App

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I have a multimodular application on Android (as you can see in the image below) .

It's a pain in the neck to switch to an specific flavor and variant in all the modules. You have to do it one by one, the worst thing is that after switch the Build Variant on each module, it starts compiling, thats a lot of time wasting.

Android Studio IDE: 3.6.3

Is there a way to do it all at once?

[image]